# log4j LogEventPatternConverter - how to log only formatted Throwable stack trace?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I have implemented a custom LogEventPatternConverter in Java, which adds a new log4j formatting directive. In my custom LogEventPatternConverter, it is firing my `format` method when a Throwable `t` is logged, e.g. with `Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getSimpleName()).error("Error", t);`

```
@Override
public void format(LogEvent event, StringBuilder toAppendTo) {
    if (event.getThrown() != null) {
        toAppendTo.append("This is a throwable");
    } else {
        toAppendTo.append(event.getMessage());
    }
}
```

In my log output, I see "This is a throwable" logged, but then the Throwable's stack trace is logged as well, apparently without going through my `format` method. Why is that? How can I intercept and format the stack trace without it being logged twice?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
// (getThrown() not null)
Throwable t = event.getThrown();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
t.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
toAppendTo.append(sw.toString());
```

Comment: Formatting the stack trace is not the issue. The problem is, even if I do this, the stack trace is logged again after I've intercepted it.

Comment: OK. Possibly a little misleading then to make the question title include *how to format Throwable stack trace?* ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - use `%throwable{0}` in your pattern to suppress the printing of the stack trace. You can still format and append it yourself in the `format` method.